# Is there a way in Range-v3 to prepend or append an element to a range/view?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, c++17, range-v3, std-ranges

Range-v3 has [`ranges::views::drop`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1actions_1_1drop__fn.html) and `ranges::views::drop_last` to remove elements from the front or the back of a view.

Does it offer a similar functions to prepend/append elements to a view?

For now, the shortest way I've found is to `concat` the range/container with a `iota` or with a `single`:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/concat.hpp>
#include <range/v3/to_container.hpp>

using namespace ranges;
using namespace views;
int main() {
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3};

    auto wi = concat(iota(0,1),v);
    assert(((wi | to_vector) == std::vector<int>{0,1,2,3}));

    auto ws = concat(single(0), v);
    assert(((ws | to_vector) == std::vector<int>{0,1,2,3}));
}
```

Comment: `concat` is the general case. You specify the two ranges of elements to join. The difference in arguments is from the asymmetry that `drop` doesn't need to know what the elements are, just how many.

Comment: @Caleth, the difference in arguments between what and what?

Comment: Taking a range vs taking a length